# what is webservice and how to use them perticularly with Delphi Prism?

Tags: web-services, mobile, remote-desktop, remote-access, delphi-prism

I am developing a software under Delphi Prism and would like to expose some part of the program to the Internet or Intranet specifically for remote access for mobile devices or a PC. Can I use web-services to do that? If so, just give me a general idea of how to go about doing that. If not, what would you use or how would you choose to accomplish this?

Your input would be greatly appreciated. Please, be as thorough as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a new web application project and add a .asmx File. A simple walkthrough, although in C#, is [presented here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359/en-us). When you are using Delphi Prism XE, you should be able to simply copy the C# code to the clipboard and paste it as Oxygene language into your project.

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways to achieve this, and 'web-services' is an umbrella term for *many* different technologies.

You may want to develop your client (usage as in 'client-server') such as a mobile application on your platform of choice (iOS, Android) and want to consume data exposed by your main application developed under Delphi Prism.

I am not familiar with Delphi Prism but there may be different ways of implementing JSON REST-like services, XML-RPC services or even SOAP services (stay away from the last, I have warned you). All these web services technologies are implemented on top of HTTP and most platforms (I assume Delphi Prism, too) support them through libraries of some sort. From iOS and Android you will then be able to easily consume your data exposed by the web service (say JSON service) and display the data in some kind of control.

A web search with the terms above will give you plenty of results (and stay away from SOAP, unless you really really need to use it).